# Managing build configurations

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I would like to create a build configuration with a selected set of source files to include for build. How do i do that in eclipse-cdt?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this related post :
[What files belong to a build target in CDT managed build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401201/what-files-belong-to-a-build-target-in-cdt-managed-build/4417943#4417943)