# What files belong to a build target in CDT managed build?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In CDT's managed builder, how are individual files assigned to build configurations?

Specifically, how can I:

- indicate that configuration A has to build and link sources from folders A and B, while configuraion B shall use folders A and C,
- include sources (not headers) from a referenced project *(or just any external source files?)*  to be also built and linked as a part of a given project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **1st point**, assuming there are 3 folders A,B & C containing .cpp files, try this :
  select folder C  in the 'project explorer' pane, right-click > exclude from build... > check configuration A > ok
  select folder B, right-click > exclude from build... > check configuration B > ok
  This way configuration A will ignore .cpp files from folder C and configuration B will ignore folder B.
- **2nd point** : maybe you could use import > general > file system to import source from an external folder into your project ?